# Why do I get an error when I pass in an integer value (of any value) to the out parameter in a method stub?

Tags: c#

I am testing a simple method that has a ref parameter as a string and an out int parameter as a integer.

I pass in the string reference variable but I get an error every time that I pass in a variable to the **out int age** parameter.

**Question: Why do i receive and Error when trying to pass in a parameter to an integer out field?**

**Error:**

Not implemented exception was not handle is the error the pops up. Nothing is in the error window at the bottom of the screen like in some types of errors.

Changed code: (But still not working)

```
  int  t = 10;
  bool a = p.testMethod("Test 0 ", out t);
```

**Code:**

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public bool testMethod(ref string text, out int age) 
        {
            int z = 100;
            age   = z;                              <-- Assign the value here
            return Int32.TryParse(text, out age);   <-- return an string
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Program p = new Program();
           bool a = p.testMethod("Test 0 Test",0);  <-- Error on this line
           bool b = p.testMethod("Test1Test",1);    <-- Error on this line 
           bool c = p.testMethod("Test22  TEST",2); <-- Error on this line
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should always indicate in which line the error is found.  It's not either of the ones you have commented...

Comment: Anytime you write, *"Why do I receive an error..."*, and **fail to include the error message**, a kitten dies.

Comment: Thank you everyone I have the code working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are passing as out parameter a constant and the same for the ref variable and do not put the appropriate keywords in front of the parameters passed to the testMethod

```
   Program p = new Program();
   int possibleValue;
   string test = "Test 0 Test";
   bool a = p.testMethod(ref test, out possibleValue);
```

However, as is, there is no need to pass the string as ref. You are not trying to change it inside the testMethod, so you could safely remove the ref for that parameter

Comment: `ref "Test 0 Test"` is no good either, that also needs a variable.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, I was looking at the obvious int value and missed the same problem on the string

Comment: Well, you noticed *something*, because you added the `ref` keyword.  But all better now.  +1

Answer (score 2):

An out parameter needs a variable as input so that it can affect the value.
You need to change the call to something like:

```
int outVal;
bool a = p.testMethod("0", out outVal);
```

This allows the calling function to set the value of 'outVal' so that the calling function can use the new value.

I also changed the "Test 0 Test", because the TryParse function will not be able to properly parse a value from that string, since it contains text.  You will also need to change the other 2 calls.

Basically, the testMethod will parse the string, and put the parsed integer value into the age variable.  So the line that sets age=z (or 100) really does not matter, since the value of age then gets changed to the result of the string parse.

And, since you are not changing the value of 'text', you do not need to pass as a reference so change the line:

```
public bool testMethod(ref string text, out int age)
```

to

```
public bool testMethod(string text, out int age)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the out reserved word in the calling parameter list to be able to use the out in the method.

```
     public void testMethod(ref string a, out int b)
     {
        //code here
     }
```

Your calling method has to look like the below call.

```
     string g = "I Like Captain America";
     int    t = 10;  
     p.testMethod(ref g, out t);
```

When I first started using C# this seemed like and odd way of programming. Why even bother with this type of syntax. But as I did more programming I found that the out parameter was extremely useful when I had to return more than one value from a function (although you should only return one parameter from a function at any time in good programming practice) but there seems to every know and then be the case where things happen and you have fudge the rules a bit. In your example you would not really need to use the ref for the string.